# Move Rectangles over Controls

Tags: c#

I have a Panel (PanelBase) with a TextBox. I need to draw and drag a rectangle over the textbox using doble buffer to eliminate the flicker. To do that I'm puting a transparent panel over de PanelBase and draw the rectangle. How can I clear the last graphics in the transparent panel?

Comment: This sounds like a winforms question.  But transparent panels that can cover a control don't exist.  Check my answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques, but what I would do is rather than try manually manage the drawing and clearing of the rectangle, I would actually create a control that has the rectangle drawn on it and then adjust the control position as you drag the mouse. This way Windows will handle the rendering and clearing for you.